# Setting up layout for timetable

Tags: android, timetable

I have a list of timetable-events and would like to lay them out as in the image.[image]

You can ignore the backgroundgrid as I will not use one.

Every event in the timetable has a start- and endtime. The height of the item in the view is related to the duration of the event. The list is observed with LiveData so changes to the timetable need to update the screen.

I considered the following approaches:

a) Using a recyclerView. Unfortunatly this either lays out the items from left to right and scrolls vertically or lays them out vertically but scrolls horizontally. I basicly need vertical layout, jumping to the next column when necessary with vertical scrolling.

b) using a gridlayout (not gridview) and spanning items over rows. Drawback is that all items need to be a multiple of a single row. This assumes all events have a duration which is a multiple of a minimum time. I can use 1 or 5 minutes as that minimum duration, but it would result in a lot of rows. Furthermore I am not sure about updating the screen, the scrolling and if this is memory efficient.

c) using a parent scroll-layout with five vertical lineairlayouts. Programmatically adding the items to the corresponding lineairlayout with the right heigth. This adds all the viewitems to the layout even if they are not visible on screen. I can forget about LiveData updates I guess.

Is there another option I have overlooked? Or can I use a recyclerView anyway? How do I do that?

P.S. I am still using Java but started to learn Kotlin

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`Android Week View`**](https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View)

- Android Week View is an android library to display calendars (week view or day view) within the app. It supports custom styling.

> **Features**

1. Week view calendar
2. Day view calendar
3. Custom styling
4. Horizontal and vertical scrolling
5. Infinite horizontal scrolling
6. Live preview of custom styling in xml preview window

Add below `dependencies`

```
implementation 'com.github.alamkanak:android-week-view:1.2.6'
```

WeekView in your xml layout.

```
<com.alamkanak.weekview.WeekView
        android:id="@+id/weekView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:eventTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:textSize="12sp"
        app:hourHeight="60dp"
        app:headerColumnPadding="8dp"
        app:headerColumnTextColor="#8f000000"
        app:headerRowPadding="12dp"
        app:columnGap="8dp"
        app:noOfVisibleDays="3"
        app:headerRowBackgroundColor="#ffefefef"
        app:dayBackgroundColor="#05000000"
        app:todayBackgroundColor="#1848adff"
        app:headerColumnBackground="#ffffffff"/>
```

Comment: Will look into this, but I intend to apply material design later. Do not see at a glance if this is possible with this library.

Comment: It is a nice library but not what I am looking for. Would not be able to put my own functionality in.

Comment: @KvdLingen yes you can

Comment: Not without taking the library apart and removing some features. I do not want a timescale at the left. Days in the weekend are not to be shown. Horizontal scrooling is not necessary.  And I want to be able to overlay two schedules. If you can and are willing to enlighten me as how to do all of that, we can continue this conversation in chat. Or make it a seperate answer I will gladly accept.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tableLayout.

Example -

```
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"  android:stretchColumns="*"  
    android:background="#ffffff">

   <TableRow
       android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="match_parent">

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/TextView04" 
       android:text="Row 2 column 1"
       android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#dcdcdc"
       android:textColor="#000000"
       android:padding="20dip"
       android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView04" 
        android:text="Row 2 column 2"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#d3d3d3"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:padding="20dip"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView04" 
        android:text="Row 2 column 3"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#cac9c9"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:padding="20dip" 
        android:gravity="center"/>

</TableRow>
```

For tutorials refer-

https://androidexample.com/Table_Layout_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=74

Comment: I have looked at TableLayout but it fills in from left to right while my list is ordered according to time which means the last item on the monday comes before the first item on the tuesday. And items can only span columns and not rows

Comment: Then you could create tableLayout programatically and set items at the required positions.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can achieve this using **FlexboxLayout**.

[Google flexbox-layout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout)

Answer (score 0):

I did not find an appropiate library or layout so I ended up writing my own view, calculating in onDraw the position of every appointment. It was not as hard as it sounds.